# Check whether tile group is a "closed loop"

Tags: javascript, algorithm, game-development, p5.js

Live: https://editor.p5js.org/s1m_t/sketches/prKfnqUJH

```
let grid;
const cols = 8;
const rows = 8;
let cellSize;

let filled = [];

class Cell {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.pos = { x: x, y: y };
    this.filled = false;
    this.isGroup = false; // some old wise man once said: the hardest part of programming is naming things
    this.group = false;
  }
}

const adj = (px, py) => {
  const adjList = [];
 
  for (let x = px - 1; x <= px + 1; x++) {
    for (let y = py - 1; y <= py + 1; y++) {
      if (x < 0 || x >= rows || y < 0 || y >= cols || (x == px && y == py)) continue;
     
      adjList.push(grid[y][x]);
    }
  }
 
  return adjList;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  cellSize = width / cols;
  initializeGrid();
}

const floodCheck = (current, group) => {
  const adjTiles = adj(current.pos.x, current.pos.y);
 
  const walls = adjTiles.filter(tile => tile.filled);

  if (walls.length === 0) return false;
 
  walls.forEach(wall => {
    if (!wall.isGroup) {
      wall.isGroup = true;
      wall.group = group;
      floodCheck(wall, group);
    }
  });
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
 
  filled.forEach(tile => {
    tile.group = false;
    tile.isGroup = false;
  });
  
  let maxGroup;

  if (filled.length > 0) {
    // group up walls
   
    let group = 0;
   
    while (true) {
      const ungrouped = filled.filter(tile => tile.group === false);
           
      if (ungrouped.length === 0) break;
           
      const startTile = ungrouped[0];
      startTile.group = group;

      let current = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(startTile));

      floodCheck(current, group);

      group++;
    }
  }
 
  for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
      if (!grid[y][x].filled) fill(255);
      else if (grid[y][x].isGroup) {
        switch (grid[y][x].group) {
          case 0: {
            fill(255, 0, 255);
            break;
          } case 1: {
            fill(100, 200, 50);
            break;
          } case 2: {
            fill(175, 50, 230);
            break;
          } default: {
            fill(0);
          }
        }
        // fill(0, 0, 255);
      }
      else fill(100);
     
      rect(x * cellSize, y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    }
  }
}

function initializeGrid() {
  grid = [];
 
  for (let y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
    grid[y] = [];
   
    for (let x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
      grid[y][x] = new Cell(x, y);
    }
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  let x = floor(mouseX / cellSize);
  let y = floor(mouseY / cellSize);

  if (grid[y][x].filled) {
    grid[y][x].filled = false;
    grid[y][x].isGroup = false;
   
    filled = filled.filter(cell => !(cell.pos.x == x && cell.pos.y == y));
  } else {
    grid[y][x].filled = true;
   
    filled.push(grid[y][x]);
  }
}
```

I've got a system in place to draw out groups of tiles, and I want to tell whether or not a group of tiles forms a "closed loop". If it does, find + store all of the tiles within the group.

**For example:**

[Example 1](https://imgur.com/dx5npOz) would fail.

[Example 2](https://imgur.com/SR01I54) would pass (highlighted tiles would be found and stored)

Comment: Could you define a "closed group" a bit more rigorously? I'm having trouble inferring what it is based on your examples. Is it just something that's thick enough to have interior tiles? Beyond that, what's the problem or specific question you have with the current code attempt? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen "thick enough"? Hm. "interior cells"? Yes. I mean a group of tiles that connects to itself, encapsulating multiple cells within the group. Look at the first example, its clearly not closed, its sort of an L shape, and it doesn't wrap around any tiles. In the second example, all 3 shapes "close in" certain tiles (the ones with emojis). Corners don't matter either, look at the sort of six shape at the left vs the other two. They would all be valid. Don't really know how to explain that.. You ever played Minecraft? Pretty much the same as a nether portal, still work without corners.

Comment: And about a problem or specific question, I just want to know how to implement what I've described into the p5 sketch I sent.

Comment: Thanks. I suggest [edit]ing that into the question so it's clearer. For the purple shape, why isn't there an emoji in the right-side tile that's totally enclosed (third cell from the top, second from the right)?

Comment: @ggorlen Third from the top, second from the right? That's a wall, I only want to get tiles within/inside the wall group itself, not part of the wall.

Comment: Well, it's different than the other wall tiles because it has no sides that touch the outside, same as 2nd from the top, 2nd from the left, which has an emoji.

Comment: @ggorlen What? The only tiles that have emojis are empty tiles. That's what I'm looking for, empty tiles within closed loops formed by groups of walls.

Comment: Yeah the spec is not clear to me then.

Comment: @ggorlen Whats not clear?

Comment: What I already asked about. One tile is clearly not on the edge (based on [VN neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood)) yet isn't given an emoji, while other tiles that are not on the edge are given emojis. The spec is unclear about what constitutes a "closed loop", or what the algorithm is supposed to do exactly.